# Is there a way to change the FileVersion of the *.vshost.exe file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

My title pretty much says it all, but a colleague has written a component that utilizes the the System.Diagnostic namespace to check the version of the running Process against a database of supported versions to determine whether or not the running version is valid.

My problem is that when I run in debug mode, the code is hosted by the compiled vshost.exe rather than my "true" exe.   I know how to control the versioning on the primary EXE, but, I'm not having much luck finding a way to control it on the *.vshost.exe.  Is there a way to do that, or should I just look for another approach?

Comment: One simple workaround is checking your filename and if it ends in .vshost.exe look at the normal exe to get the version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find a way to change the file version, here's a workaround that someone might find usefull.

Consider [disabling the hosting process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for your project.  You can uncheck the 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process' option in your Project Properties's Debug tab.

Edit: Added link to what the [hosting process does for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: This isn't quite what I was hoping to hear, but it looks like a good solution.   From your link, it looks as though the hosting process isn't as important as I thought it might be, so all-in-all, this seems like a pretty good approach.  Thanks!